SyncFusion tabView scroll content problem in net Maui
it's simple, the scroll is not working on this easy example and it's driving me crazy
<ContentPage.Content>
<StackLayout>
    <tabView:SfTabView >
        <tabView:SfTabView.Items>
            <tabView:SfTabItem Header="Tab 1">
                <tabView:SfTabItem.Content>
                    <ScrollView BackgroundColor="Yellow" Margin="40" Padding="40">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="400">
                                <Label Text="Content 1" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="400" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="400" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                                <Label Text="Content 2" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="400" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ScrollView>
                </tabView:SfTabItem.Content>
            </tabView:SfTabItem>
        </tabView:SfTabView.Items>
    </tabView:SfTabView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>

I'm stuck and don't know what more try

it will only scroll if the contents of the ScrollView are larger than the ScrollView container

This is by design. A vertically-oriented StackLayout is supposed to render its child elements as much vertical space as possible; The ScrollView inside the StackLayout gets all the space it wants (enough to fill the entire  StackLayout). Since the ScrollView's viewport is not vertically constrained or restrained, there's no reason for it to scroll.
To make it work, you can replace the outer StackLayout with a Grid like below:
<ContentPage.Content>

    <Grid>
         <tabView:SfTabView >
         ...
            <ScrollView BackgroundColor="Yellow" Margin="40" Padding="40">

               <!--Omitted for brevity>--> 
                    
            </ScrollView>

          ...           
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>

